# Dynamically add code at runtime in VB(.NET)

Tags: vb.net, button

I want to make a program in VB(.NET) in which per click on a button one or more new buttons are added to the UserForm. This process should work for an infinite number of times. Then the buttons shall call a public sub, handing over an individual variable so that the code knows what button it was called from (thus: knows what to do).

I learned how to create buttons at runtime with the `Button = new Button` and `controls.add(Button)` code. I also managed to pass a new code to the button by using `WithEvents` or an `AddHandler`. But until now I always need to have the code ready before the program is run. I.e. I need to know the name of the button in advance and have the code prepared.

Is there a way to dynamically create a code snipped at run time that will point to a pre-existing one?

I'll give you a simplyfied example:

```
WithEvents NewButton01 As New Button
WithEvents NewButton02 As New Button
WithEvents NewButton03 As New Button

Private Sub AddNewButton_Click() Handles AddNewButton.Click

    NewButton01.Location = New Point(10, 10)
    NewButton01.Text = "01"
    Controls.Add(NewButton01)

    NewButton02.Location = New Point(50, 50)
    NewButton02.Text = "02"
    Controls.Add(NewButton02)

    NewButton03.Location = New Point(90, 90)
    NewButton03.Text = "03"
    Controls.Add(NewButton03)

End Sub

Private Sub NewButton01_click() Handles NewButton01.Click
    Call MessageBox(1)
End Sub

Private Sub NewButton02_click() Handles NewButton02.Click
    Call MessageBox(2)
End Sub

Private Sub NewButton03_click() Handles NewButton03.Click
    Call MessageBox(3)
End Sub

Private Sub MessageBox(flag As Integer)
    MsgBox("You activated button number " & flag)
End Sub
```

As you can see, this is a very unprofessional way of coding. Also, I'd like to keep the amount of buttons created infinite, so I can't use this code. I'd rather have VB make a new button each time I click on "AddNewButton" and write a code that refers to `Private Sub MessageBox` or whatever code it may be in the end.

I am very new to VB.Net, so please forgive me if the examples contains anything that makes you shiver.

And thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might help:

```
    Private Sub AddNewButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim lastButtonPos As Integer = 10
        For i = 1 To 3
            Dim NewButton As New Button
            NewButton.Location = New Point(lastButtonPos, lastButtonPos)
            NewButton.Text = "0" & i.ToString
            NewButton.Name = i.ToString
            AddHandler NewButton.Click, AddressOf Button_click
            Controls.Add(NewButton)
            lastButtonPos = lastButtonPos + 40
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim clickedButton As Button = CType(sender, Button)
        Dim clickedNumber As Integer = clickedButton.Name
        Call MessageBox(clickedNumber)
    End Sub

    Private Sub MessageBox(flag As Integer)
        MsgBox("You activated button number " & flag)
    End Sub
```

Comment: You'd have to make lastButtonPos Static or make it a class variable to use this multiple times.  I'd use a FlowLayoutPanel instead, and just do FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(NewButton) so the positioning is all handled for you.

Comment: Yeah I agree the implementation could be better but I wanted to show the dynamic event handler assignment and type casting in the event handler. I remember how exciting it was when I realised about type casting :D

Comment: Thanks for the code! It sure works, but I still need to understand what happens there. Do I get that right: "sender" is a variable which tells a Private Sub from where it was executed. In this case, the "sender" is button1. Now you make "button1" become a button and assign it to the newly defined Button "clickedButton"?

Comment: No problem, plz mark as answer if it answered your question ;-)

Comment: The CType type cast statment allows you to convert the incoming object into the expected type so you can use it's properties and methods. You could test the type such as this: If TypeOf(sender) Is Button Then...before casting to button. You could also handle other control types if needs be...

Comment: That would be great, because I might end of working with clickable text boxes instead of Buttons, not sure...also, Capellan's hint was great too. I do have to think about how to layout all those buttons in the end, so I'll have a look at FlowLayoutPanel too. Thanks!